# Working with pascal style strings in c++

Tags: c++

Addins for Excel (xll) use strings where the first character is the length of string and there is no null termination.

Currently I use a struct which contains an array of wchar_t with length equal to the length of the excel string+1. I copy the excel string (including the length char) into array[0] and put a '\0' at the end of the array. This way I can work on it as an excel string and a cstring

I would prefer to work on these strings directly as opposed to copying them.
 The functions I require are the basic string functions; strlen, cmp, trim, substr,replace etc. Had a look for a library bit r couldn't find any.

Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: There are no standard functions in `string.h` for Pascal strings. But all of those basic operations can easily be re-implemented. ... Your `strlen`, for example, can be implemented as `return str[0];`. (That said: `trim` and `substr` are neither a standard C nor C++ string functions.)

Comment: @Jongware I can write it myself but first I wanted to see if it was part of the STL or if there was a library out there already.

Comment: It isn't part of the STL, and if there's a library out there already you can probably find it by searching. Tool recommendations are explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining such structure:

```
typedef struct _VarLengthStr
{
    unsigned int    length;
    unsigned char   string[1];
} VarLengthStr, *PVarLengthStr;
```

You may need different type for length. Also you need allocate memory with `new` or `malloc`

---

Also you may use safe functions like [`strnlen_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50ty2zh.aspx) instead of `strlen` and etc.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing but it requires me to copy in from the source string. I want to work directly on the source.

Comment: @user425678 you may cast data pointer to pointer of this structure and work this way.

Comment: Standard functions require a null termination which the excel strings don't have and I can't insert one at the end without copying the data.

Comment: @user425678 I have updated answer and added link, please take a look, it doesn't require NULL termination and there are similar functions for different purposes.